# How can a GameObject be created in my chosen position when a button is clicked.unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, gameobject

I want to spawn 4 game objects in my chosen positions when a Button is clicked.Unity 2D C#

Comment: What point are you at currently? Do you have a button which calls a function yet? If so, then get references to the prefabs you want to spawn in, call [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) on each of them and spawn them in at specified [Vector2](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.html) locations

Comment: Can you add some code and show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Instantiate(yourPrefabObject, yourTranformPossition);

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Apparently I didn't understand your question right.
if your button object uses a collider. you can detect mouse events on that object.
assign this script to your object that has collider.

```
public Transform prefabToCreate;
public Vector2 posToCreate = Vector2.zero;

void OnMouseDown() {
    Instantiate(prefabToCreate, posToCreate, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

It's easy to figure out how to make the object 4 times.

p.s: you should explain your question in more detail.

Comment: This... times 4.  :)

Comment: OP said 'when a button is clicked', which is not the same as Input.GetMouseButtonDown

Comment: Thanks i figured it out.